# Load multiple large images in single ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have multiple large images and I would like to use these in such a way that it would allow users to do continuous panning. I couldn't stitch all the images into one image as it would give memory limit error. Also I want to compress the images. I believe one option is to place the images in a virtual grid shape and show image based on current viewport & touch position (it might have some issues when switching between images). I was wondering if there is any other easy ways to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can split the images into smaller ones and load only the images currently visible on the screen and probably the next one to provide smoothness while panning. So if you have 6000x4000 you may want to automatically split them into 24 images 1000x1000.